# EF Core 3.1 Specify different default value functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am struggling with the migration of my app with EF Core 3.1.

My app needs to be compatible Oracle / SQL Server and therefore I need to be able to provide a solution handling the default value of a `DateTime` column.

Could you help me to be able to code that the default value function should differ depending of the database type:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntityName> builder)
{
    // SQL Server
    builder.Property(auh => auh.MyEntityProperty);
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");

    // Oracle
    builder.Property(auh => auh.MyEntityProperty);
            .HasDefaultValueSql("sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)");
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Iria this isn't a "what have you tried" question. Migrations only work for simple scenarios and this isn't one

Comment: It's not so simple, you can set up different models with different values, one model for each database or the other option, have a property in the model called databasetype, then you don't save this value but you use it to workout the other value, the default time, and the advantage of this is that you can use to set up any other database dependant parameter

Comment: @Pagnagiotis, I partially agree with you, it is not a simple migration, it involves a lot of work. Trust me, I have seen similar scenarios and as I said I can think of 2 workarounds

Comment: That's just one of the reasons why migrations are *not* meant for complex scenarios. They're mainly meant for development, not actually generating a production schema. **Especially** when that schema will have to be inspected and approved by an Oracle DBA before it gets created. Which is unlikely to happen. It's better to use `HasDefaultvalue()` alone, without a value, to tell EF that the column will have a database-generated default, and created the tables with SQL scripts.

Comment: @Iria the workaround is to not try to use the ORM to generate the database. That only works for very simple cases. And any Oracle DBA (and most SQL Server DBAs) would reject ORM-generated schemas anyway. Using a different model per database is no option, when the only thing that changes is a single string. Even if it's 10 strings. Using a `databasetype` is no option either because database-specific code will leak into all application DbContexts. Something that could work would be to inject and use a service that provides pre-defined default expressions and register db-specific implementations

Comment: I would be also willing to consider another solution: is there's one where a default value for a date specifies the datetime of NOW() (considering UTC) and which would be cross database in EF?

Comment: The problem isn't Entity Framework. All database products offer only basic conformance to the SQL standard. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` works across many databases for *local* time. If you use dependency injection to create the DbContext, you can register a database specific object with default expressions at startup, add it as a dependency to the constructor that accepts `DbContextOptions` and use the expressions it provides. Eg if you create an `interface IDbDefaults { public string UtcNowExpression {get;}}` you can register an `OracleDefaults:IDbDefaults` that returns `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`